# Perform onclick event of listview on activiy start up

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to perform OnClick event of my custom listview on Activity Start. but its not working.

```
 listTimer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTimer);
    TimerAdapter tadapt = new TimerAdapter(RoutineList, this);
            listTimer.setAdapter(tadapt);
```

I already try all possibilities which are mention below:

```
//listTimer.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    //listTimer.setSelection(1);
    //listTimer.setSelected(true);
    //listTimer.requestFocus();
    //listTimer.performItemClick(listTimer, 1, listTimer.getItemIdAtPosition(1));
   // listTimer.requestFocus();
```

But Not single one helped me to get out of this problem. I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: you mean want to click listview itemclick ?

Comment: what you want click or just focus on first item ?

Comment: yes, i want to click on first item of listview with focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just smell you are trying to achieve auto click on first row of listview, Initially you have to initialize your `list-view and override onItemClickListner` like below:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked"+mList.get(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("clicked", "^^^^^^");

                v = arg0;
                id=arg3;

            }
        });
```

Now make object of `View`  and `long` globally and assign inside onItemclickLisnter:

```
View v=null;
long id;
```

Lastly put below piece of code inside `onResume();`, as you mention you want to click first item then pass `0`(zero) else as per requirement.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        listview.performItemClick(v, 0, id);
        super.onResume();
    }
```